# How can we implement marker zoom in and out functionality on google map

Tags: android, android-maps

How can we implement marker zoom in and out functionality on google map,
while user trying to zoom in or out google map.

Comment: you cant zoom in zoom out marker programmatically.

Comment: if you have any suggestion please let me know.

Comment: Just set a marker to your map and it will take care of zooming in and out, marker's dimension will adjust automatically

Comment: +1, the size of the marker adjusts automatically. Are you talking about something else? Like you want to increase the size of the marker?

Comment: Yes i am not talking about marker adjusts automatically. i want increase the size of the marker when user zoom in or zoom out of map. @ SowingFiber

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. It may help you.

```
public Bitmap bitmapSizeByScall( Bitmap bitmapIn, float scall_zero_to_one_f) {
Bitmap bitmapOut = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapIn,
        Math.round(bitmapIn.getWidth() * scall_zero_to_one_f),
        Math.round(bitmapIn.getHeight() * scall_zero_to_one_f), false);

return bitmapOut;
```

}

Comment: i am not talking about Adds a ground overlay with 50% transparency

Comment: @taruntakyar try resizing the icon

Comment: i am not talking about icon we are using marker. So how can be change the size of marker.